# How to correctly change the number of columns and their names after creating the treeview (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to create my own class treeview

I ran into the fact that after trying to change the number of columns, it persistently creates one more.

I can't figure out why this is happening and how to change it.

Help.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class TableTreeView (ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

    def create_columns(self, columns_count):
        columns_names = []
        for i in range(columns_count):
            columns_names.append('№'+str(i+1))
        columns_names = tuple(columns_names)
        self['columns'] = columns_names
        for i in range(columns_count):
            self.heading(columns_names[i], text=columns_names[i])

root = tkinter.Tk()
table = TableTreeView(root)
table.create_columns(2)
table.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I have also tried this approach:
`self.config({"columns": columns_names})`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use append command to change. You can change existing object by reaching it **self** or other pointed variables and set it's content like below

```
self['show'] = 'headings'
```